# Converting a large list into a data.frame

Tags: r, performance, memory-management, dataframe

I am trying to convert a list of 13,000 elements, each element being a `zoo` object with nr = 230 and ncol = 4, to a dataframe.

I have tried `setattr(mylist, 'class', 'data.frame')`, but it resulted in a huge vector of NAs.
I have also tried the `quickdf(mylist)` function from the `plyr` package, but that didn't work either.

The `do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist)`type methods are very slow, thus not an option in this case.

Any suggestion as to the most efficient method to convert such a list to a dataframe?

Comment: Please don't add redundant tag names in titles.

Comment: Which tag is redundant?

Comment: The [tag:R] tag (in the title).

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to this forum and still getting used to the "rules". Please bear with me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use rbindlist from the data.table package.

```
data <- matrix(data = 1, nrow = 230, ncol = 4)
lstData <- rep(list(data), 16000)

library(data.table)
lstData <- Map(as.data.frame, lstData)
dfrData <- rbindlist(lstData)


system.time(dfrData <- rbindlist(lstData))
user  system elapsed 
0.12    0.03    0.15
```

Comment: It works great! The result is a `data.table` and I simply convert it to a data.frame afterwards! Thanks!!

Comment: 1. for a time series I would use xts. It is basically zoo but optimized for speed. 2. You can just do rbindlist for the dates itself. `lstIndex <- Map(as.data.frame, Map(index, lstData))
dfrIndex <- rbindlist(lstIndex)
setnames(dfrIndex, "Date")

lstData <- Map(as.data.frame, lstData)
dfrData <- rbindlist(lstData)

zooResult <- as.zoo(dfrData, as.Date(dfrIndex$Date))`

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thanks a lot! I would have upvoted you answer, I just don't have enough reputation for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is efficient, but you can try

```
library(plyr)
ldply(mylist)
```

Comment: As I specified in the question, `docall.rbind(mylist)` is not an option since it is not efficient from a memory management standpoint, and incurs a huge run time. I have not tried `ldply(mylist)` though.. Will try that, thanks!

Comment: I have erased that one.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently trying `ldply(mylist)` and it is extremely slow.. I will let it run and report the runtime, if it is not excessive. Still I believe there must be a more efficient method in this case..

Comment: Well, it gave the following error: `Error in matrix(NA, nrow = nrows, ncol = length(cols)) : too many elements specified`

Comment: I split it in 5 and still got that error... I am not sure if this is due to the fact that each element of the list is itself a zoo object with 4 columns

Comment: Try this: `ldply(mylist,fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks Metrics! That still took a long time! Wolfgang Wu's answer solved my problem though! Thanks for trying.

Comment: FYI: `data.table` is suitable for big data and that is what you have.